# Is there a way to find the longest path in a weighted graph with an exact amount of connections?

Tags: python, graph, path, path-finding

Is there a way to find the longest path with a set amount of edges?
Like: I wanna find the longest path (with exactly 5 connections) in a weighted graph.
The graph can look like this for example..

```
Graph = [
('0', '1', 4.3), ('0', '2', 4.8), ('0', '3', 2.7), ('0', '4', 2.6), ('1', '2', 4.8), 
('1', '3', 2.7), ('1', '4', 2.6), ('2', '3', 2.7), ('2', '4', 2.6), ('2', '5', 3.6), 
('2', '6', 0.8), ('3', '4', 2.6), ('3', '5', 3.6), ('3', '6', 0.8), ('3', '7', 4.4),
 ('4', '5', 3.6), ('4', '6', 0.8), ('4', '7', 4.4), ('5', '6', 0.8), ('5', '7', 4.4), 
('6', '7', 4.4), ('7', '8', 2.8), ('7', '9', 2.6), ('8', '9', 2.6), ('8', '10', 2.1),
 ('8', '11', 2.8), ('9', '10', 2.1), ('9', '11', 2.8), ('10', '11', 2.8),
 ('10', '12', 3.3), ('10', '13', 5), ('11', '12', 3.3), ('11', '13', 5), 
('12', '13', 5)
]
```

Now.. How can I get from "0" to "13" in exactly 5 steps and make the cost as big as possible?

Also I am using python.

Comment: Do you know how to find *any* path from "0" to "13"?

Comment: Yeah but this doesnt help me

Comment: Do you know how to find *all* paths from "0" to "13"?

Comment: Yeah but this also doesnt help because in big graphs with 1.5k+ nodes and 400k+ edges, it takes ages to collect all paths.

Comment: But maybe this will help you in finding only those paths with 5 connections (by skipping a path if it didn't reach "13" after 5 steps).

Comment: Since you didn't post any code, I'll just offer some generic advice. Figure out if you can repeat nodes or edges. Do a basic DFS, tracking the depth. The exact number of steps gives you a termination condition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a breadth-first search to find all the paths to `13`, updating a running weight count and path:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
Graph = [('0', '1', 4.3), ('0', '2', 4.8), ('0', '3', 2.7), ('0', '4', 2.6), ('1', '2', 4.8), ('1', '3', 2.7), ('1', '4', 2.6), ('2', '3', 2.7), ('2', '4', 2.6), ('2', '5', 3.6), ('2', '6', 0.8), ('3', '4', 2.6), ('3', '5', 3.6), ('3', '6', 0.8), ('3', '7', 4.4), ('4', '5', 3.6), ('4', '6', 0.8), ('4', '7', 4.4), ('5', '6', 0.8), ('5', '7', 4.4), ('6', '7', 4.4), ('7', '8', 2.8), ('7', '9', 2.6), ('8', '9', 2.6), ('8', '10', 2.1), ('8', '11', 2.8), ('9', '10', 2.1), ('9', '11', 2.8), ('10', '11', 2.8), ('10', '12', 3.3), ('10', '13', 5), ('11', '12', 3.3), ('11', '13', 5), ('12', '13', 5)]
d, q = defaultdict(list), deque([('0', 0, [])])
t, s = '13', 5 #target node and number of steps to target
d1 = {t:(0, [])}
for a, *b in Graph:
   d[a].append(b)

while q:
   a, b, c = q.popleft()
   if a == t and len(c) == s:
      if d1[a][0] < b:
          d1[a] = (b, c)
   if len(c+[a]) <= s:
      for x, y in d[a]:
         q.append((x, b+y, c+[a]))

print(d1['13'])
```

Output:

```
(17.7, ['0', '3', '7', '8', '11'])
```

---

A possible method to speedup the search is to work backwards from the target node to the start node, thus reducing the total branching that occurs when normally starting from the root:

```
d, q = defaultdict(list), deque([('13', 0, [])])
t, s = '0', 5 #target node and number of steps to target
d1 = {t:(0, [])}
for a, b, c in Graph:
   d[b].append((a, c))

while q:
   a, b, c = q.popleft()
   if a == t and len(c) == s:
      if d1[a][0] < b:
          d1[a] = (b, c)
   if len(c+[a]) <= s:
      for x, y in d[a]:
         q.append((x, b+y, c+[a]))

w, _p = d1[t]
print((w, (_p[1:]+[t])[::-1]))
```

Output:

```
(17.7, ['0', '3', '7', '8', '11'])
```

Comment: It works for small graphs, but it takes ages for larger graphs and never stops executing, is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: @MonkeiProtec is your graph cyclic?

Comment: Its a directed acyclic graph

Comment: @MonkeiProtec Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Yeah it works a lot faster now but still not fast enough to solve for graphs with 1.5k nodes (440k edges)

Comment: @MonkeiProtec See my recent edit.

Comment: Its still wayy to slow.. I uploaded an example graph here:
https://justpaste.it/1xva8
It has 501 Nodes and we need to go from node 0 to node 501

Comment: @MonkeiProtec What are the start-end nodes when using that large graph?

Comment: "0" is start Node and "501" is end Node

Comment: @MonkeiProtec What is the allowed path length?

Comment: It also needs to have path length of 5